# I want to split the string with if it satisfies some conditions in python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

```
my_str = 'According to the teacher, "He never believed what I said. He ran away." And I think he did indeed. I tried to find him, but I could not.'
```

The result should be:

```
['According to the teacher, "He never believed what I said. He ran away." And I think he did indeed.', 'I tried to find him, but I could not.']
```

In this string I want to split it by .(dot)
However, I don't want to split it if .(dot) is in " "(quotation)

How can I do it using `re.split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no answer that works for all strings here. The type of logic you're describing requires more than the "Regular" grammar that regex operates in. You'll have to create your own custom logic, like:

```py
def custom_split_string(s: str) -> List[str]:
    output = []
    in_quote = False
    word = []
    for ch in s:
        word.append(ch)
        if ch == "." and not in_quote:
            output.append(''.join(word))
            word.clear()
        elif ch == '"':
            in_quote = not in_quote  # assume no nested quotes
    return output

my_str = 'According to the teacher, "He never believed what I said. He ran away." And I think he did indeed. I tried to find him, but I could not.'

expected_output = ['According to the teacher, "He never believed what I said. He ran away." And I think he did indeed.', ' I tried to find him, but I could not.']

assert custom_split_string(my_str) == expected_output
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `.findall`, with:

```
(?:[^."]+"[^"]+")*[^."]+\.
```

https://regex101.com/r/d400Ut/1

- `(?:[^."]+"[^"]+")*` - Repeat 0 or more times:

  - `[^."]+` Non-`".` characters, followed by
  - `"[^"]+"` - Characters inside quotes
- `[^."]+\.` - Match non-`."` characters, followed by a period

```
matches = re.findall(r'(?:[^."]+"[^"]+")*[^."]+\.', my_str)
```